# How do I save and retrieve image from specific folder of another computer which is in same network?

Tags: c#

I am working on a WPF application where I want to save image to a specific folder of another computer within same network and retrieve any image from the same folder to show on my application.

Need some references, tutorials.

Comment: why WPF tag????

Comment: If you were logged in on the same machine where your WPF application runs, how would you manage to save the file manually? Is there a UNC share? Mapped drive? Ftp location? Work out the manual process and we can tell you how to do it in code. And if you find you can't actually do it manually (e.g. due to access restrictions), then there is no way a program can do it either.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  While the answer below is appropriate, there's likely dozens of ways that someone could answer this question.  OP - Consider expanding on @JohnWu comment and elaborate on how you plan to make the destination available (UNC, FTP, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explanation is true for the Windows OS.
Let's assume that you have some other machine in your network named "PC1".
PC1 has a hard disk named "C".
On this disk you have a folder SharedFolder, let local path be "C:\SampleFolder\SharedFolder".

Than you need to right click on that folder and choose share, the manual could be found [here](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-share-a-folder-over-your-network-5808814).
After you choose the people with who you want to share the path will be written, something like "\\DESKTOP_MIKE\SharedFolder".

Finally, you can use this path on the other machine to target that specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to share that folder, then you could use `System.IO.File.Copy` or directly read using UNC paths.

***UNC:  \\SERVERNAME\ShareName***

https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/533544-reading-file-unc-path-c-net

If there is a share named  C_DRIVE on machine TOM_PC then you could perform a simple test at a CMD prompt:

```
DIR \\TOM_PC\C_DRIVE\*.*
```

Comment: can you give me some detail to perform this

Comment: Or it could be done using another service, such as http, ftp, tftp, etc.

Comment: yes, of course but it doesn't sound necessary in this case.  Sharing would be the simplest for an app that would only ever run in a controlled network.